# Call Servlet ResourceType method post in AEM

Tags: java, aem

I got block in call servlet with method post in aem.
I have servlet with resourceType, method post. I don't know how to call this servlet in html/jsp.

Can you help me clear this case ?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your servlet registered with resourceType is called when a URL which resolves to that resourceType is invoked.

eg: if your servlet is registered with the resourceType of `/example/whatever` and when you call page, say /content/we-retail/en.html which has a sling:resourceType of `/example/whatever`, then your servlet gets called.

Usually when you register a servlet with resourceTypes property, you add additional properties to narrow down the scope of the servlet using extensions or selectors or http method, etc. This is because many other pages might have the same resourceType and you might not want to invoke your servlet in those cases.